# Maven Release Plugin - svn: E200007: Source and destination URLs appear not to point to the same repository

Tags: maven, svn, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I'm getting this error during the mvn release:prepare goal:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare (default-cli) on project env-status-checks: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn tag command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: E200007: Source and destination URLs appear not to point to the same repository.
```

That's the failing SVN command

```
[INFO] Tagging release with the label env-status-checks-0.0.1...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --username akanchev --password ***** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive copy --file C:\Windows\TEMP\maven-scm-1102804858.commit --revision 9260 svn://svn.XXXX.local/qa/XX-tf/trunk/env-status-checks http://svn.XXXX.local/qa/XX-tf/tags/env-status-checks-0.0.1"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\Administrator\.jenkins\jobs\Test release\workspace

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The pom.xml config for the maven release plugin is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
       <configuration>
          <tagBase>http://svn.XXXX.local/qa/XX-tf/tags</tagBase>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And that's the SVN scm:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:svn://svn.XXX.local/qa/wh-tf/trunk/env-status-checks</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://svn.XXX.local/qa/XX-tf/trunk/env-status-checks</developerConnection>
    <url>scm:svn:svn://svn.XXX.local/qa/XX-tf/</url>        
</scm>
```

FINAL SOLUTION (thanks Ben):

I was actually fooled by the maven guide for the release plugin. In the example there

```
<tagBase>https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/myapplication/releases</tagBase>
```

What worked properly for me is:

TAG base

```
<tagBase>svn://svn.XXXX.local/qa/XX-tf/tags/</tagBase>
```

SCM connection

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:svn:svn://svn.XXXX.local/qa/XX-tf/trunk/env-status-checks</connection>
 </scm>
```

Comment: So I  have try with

<scm>
  <connection>scm:svn://svn.XXXX.local/qa/XX-tf/trunk/env-status-checks</connection>

<br/>
<scm>
  <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.XXXX.local/qa/XX-tf/trunk/env-status-checks</connection>
 </scm>

<scm>
  <connection>scm:svn:https://svn.XXXX.local/qa/XX-tf/trunk/env-status-checks</connection>
 </scm>

Nothing worked.

Comment: remove maven from the equation. run that SVN command by itself and confirm why it doesn't work. Once you fix it in svn, introduce maven again and see what you need to give it so that it produces the working SVN command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your svn copy command is mixing two different protocols.  The source is svn:// and the destination is http://.  You need to use the same protocol when doing a server side copy since the destination and source have to be reachable via the same connection.

Switching to using both via svn:// or both via http:// should solve your problem.